# require (and pass values to) browserify modules from my page/html

Tags: javascript, requirejs, gulp, browserify

I am converting my requirejs + play framework asset pipeline to gulp/browserify. It's been a great journey so far. However, I have hit a major roadblock.

When I used requireJs, I could do something like this on my page:

```
var pageSpecificConstant = @configJsonObj; //something my server gives me.
require(['jquery', 'unsubscribe'], function($,  unsubscribe) {
    $(function () {
        unsubscribe.init(pageSpecificConstant);
    });
});
```

Basically, I need to pass some page level data to at least SOME module.

Now with gulp/browserify (and factor plugin), I am generating 2 packages:

```
<script src="js/bundles/unsubscribe.js"></script>
<script src="js/bundles/common.js"></script>
```

Now I would love to do something like before:

```
var unsubscribe = require('unsubscribe'); //or require(path_to_unsubscribe.js file)
```

Unfortunately this isn't possible with browserify.

I am wondering what my options are. I read about a "standalone" option for browserify, but I wasn't completely clear how to use it since I'm generating multiple bundles.

Here's the browserify step of my gulp (it's still in prototype stage)

```
browserify: function() {
        var bundler = browserify(['./public/javascripts/unsubscribe.js', './public/javascripts/homepage.js'], {
            debug: !production,
            transform: [stringify({
                    extensions: ['.html', '.mustache', '.handlebars'],
                    minify: true,
                    minifier: {
                        extensions: ['.html', '.mustache', '.handlebars']       
                    }
                }),
                [browserifyCss, {
                    'autoInject': true,
                    'rootDir': './public/target/css'
                }]
            ],
            globals: true,
            cache: {}
        })

        var build = argv._.length ? argv._[0] === 'build' : false;
        if (watch) {
            bundler = watchify(bundler);
        }
        var rebundle = function() {
            return bundler
            .plugin(factorBundle, {
                //factor-bundle plugin
                // File output order must match entry order
                o: ['./public/target/javascripts/bundles/unsubscribe.js', './public/target/javascripts/bundles/homepage.js']
            })
            .bundle()
            .on('error', handleError('Browserify'))
            .pipe(source('common.js'))
            .pipe(gulpif(production, buffer()))
            .pipe(gulpif(production, uglify()))
            .pipe(gulpif(production, gzip()))
            .pipe(gulp.dest('./public/target/javascripts/bundles'));
        };
        bundler.on('update', rebundle);
        return rebundle();
    }
```

I just need some way to pass values to my browserify modules from the page. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you want. Why not expose an `init` method on the module that you can call with page data? You could potentially use `[externalize](https://github.com/epeli/browserify-externalize)` if you want to  lazily load modules in.

Comment: The problem is I'm supporting an old platform that passes lots of page specific settings/variables to the JS through the init method of the module. You might argue I could make a get request and fetch these, but that will involve a lot of refactoring on some of the pages. 
I don't want to lazily load modules because technically they are already available due to the bundles I am loading on the page. I just can't figure how to "require" them.

Comment: If `module` has an `init` method on it, and you are writing `pageSpecificVariable` to the window, you should just be able to do `module.init(global.pageSpecificVariable)` and it will work in the same way.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. That's definitely one way to go about it. I'm still hoping I could do some testing of modules from my browser etc. I found this - https://www.npmjs.com/package/requireify
I'll let you know if it works out for us.

Answer (score 0):

For a quick solution I exported the app in the entry point, so if your `/path/to/bootstrap.js` looks like:

```
var app    = require("./app.js"),
    config = requrie("./config.js");

app.init(config)
   .run();
```

Then change the entry point to a file `/path/to/export.js` containing:

```
var app = require("./app.js");

window.app = app;
```

Then in the page (I'm using PHP):

```
app.init(
    <?php echo json_encode($config); ?>
)
.run();
```